# Xcode 11, default Storyboard missing

Tags: storyboard, xcode11

In Xcode 11, default Storyboard is missing when a new project is created. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While Creating a new project, simply select Storyboard, its SwiftUI by default in the new project options wizard.

[image]